# dynamic_cast of void *

Tags: c++

I need to use dynamic cast void*

```
void *target = (MYClass*)target;//I am storing initially(to implment delegate mechanism)
....
delegateClass *delegate = dynamic_cast<delegateClass*>(target);
```

It is giving error cannot convert void*, I cannot use below code... since it is a delegate mechanism

```
delegateClass *delegate = dynamic_cast<delegateClass*>(((MYClass*))target);
```

How to get the type of target and implement... If i use typeid() i can get the name of the class but how to use typeid in the above equation instead of (((MYClass*))target).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic cast unless the original type of the variable had a vtable (ie, had virtual functions). This is because dynamic_cast requires run-time type information, which is recorded in the vtable; if the vtable is missing, the compiler doesn't know what type the object is.

You should declare a base class with a virtual destructor, and use pointers to this base class rather than `void *`.

Comment: Nice idea... I have created a simple root class(contains virtual destructor) and instead of void* I used that CRoot*... So any class which needs to get delegate has to to be inherited from CRoot.

Answer (score 2):

If you must pass the object as a `void *` then you should use

```
delegateClass *delegate = static_cast<delegateClass*>(((MYClass*))target);
```

as there is no class relationship between the `void *target` and `delegateClass`. Here you are saying that you know that target _is_a_ delegateClass.

However this idiom is usually used for passing code through standard C interfaces and back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation and being learning c++ style type casting. I referred to this llink http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

From this what I can interpret is that the purpose of dynamic_cast is to ensure that the result of the type conversion is a valid complete object of the requested class. So when we try to convert from derived class to base class the conversion is smooth. But the vice versa is not true.

```
class CBase { };
class CDerived: public CBase { };

CBase b; CBase* pb;
CDerived d; CDerived* pd;

pb = dynamic_cast<CBase*>(&d);     // ok: derived-to-base
pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(&b);  // wrong: base-to-derived
```

Now for that to work the base class should be polymorphic i.e. it should have a virtual function. When a class is polymorphic, dynamic_cast performs a special checking during runtime to ensure that the expression yields a valid complete object of the requested class. Have a look here.

```
class CBase { virtual void dummy() {} };
class CDerived: public CBase { int a; };

int main () {
  try {
    CBase * pba = new CDerived;
    CBase * pbb = new CBase;
    CDerived * pd;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast" << endl;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pbb);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast" << endl;

  } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}
  return 0;
}
```

Here the code tries to perform two dynamic casts from pointer objects of type CBase* (pba and pbb) to a pointer object of type CDerived*, but only the first one is successful. Even though both are pointers of type CBase*, pba points to an object of type CDerived, while pbb points to an object of type CBase. Thus, when their respective type-castings are performed using dynamic_cast, pba is pointing to a full object of class CDerived, whereas pbb is pointing to an object of class CBase, which is an incomplete object of class CDerived so it returns a null pointer to indicate the failure.

So I'd suggest you to make use of the static_cast which offers bi directional type casting i.e. from derived to base class and also from derived to base class. But in that case  programmer needs to ensure that the conversion is safe becasue the type checking is not performed at run time as in case of dynamic_cast.

In your code here either make target to point to deligate class object before conversion(but make sure Myclass is polymorphic) otherwise you can go for static_cast.

This explaination is based on my very recent reading on the topic and I'd suggest you to refer to Effective C++ for more insight about this. I hope this will help. :)