# Why is `boost::any` better than `void*`?

Tags: c++, boost, void-pointers, variadic

What inherent advantages do `boost::any` and `boost::any_cast` offer over using `void*` and `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: You can't `dynamic_cast` from `void*`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I always assumed that was possible to do, though I never tried it... :|

Comment: @PaulManta regarding the comment of Armen, you could have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771998/dynamic-cast-of-void

Comment: The magic of boost::any comes with some performance cost, though. https://felipedelamuerte.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/why-you-shouldnt-use-boostany-especially-not-in-time-critical-code/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The advantage is that `boost::any` is way more type-safe than `void*`.

E.g.

```
int i = 5;
void* p = &i;
static_cast<double*>(p);  //Compiler doesn't complain. Undefined Behavior.
boost::any a;
a = i;
boost::any_cast<double>(a); //throws, which is good
```

As to your comment, you cannot `dynamic_cast` from a `void*`. You can `dynamic_cast` only from pointers and references to class types which have at least one virtual function (aka polymorphic types)

Comment: Yeah, but that's a static cast, not a dynamic cast. Your comment that you can't use `dynamic_cast` on `void*` was a better answer. Or was your point that there's nothing stopping you from using `static_cast` even though you shouldn't? :)

Comment: @Paul: Added that part to my answer

Answer (score 16):

`boost::any` calls destructors:

```
{
    boost::any x = std::string("Hello, world");
    x = std::wstring(L"Goodbye"); // string::~string called here
} // wstring::~wstring called here
```

Answer (score 9):

somehow nobody mentioned that boost::any<> acts as a value type, where as void* is a pointer. That means that any<> can store ANY object of ANY size.  Once stored, you can pass the variable of any<> type anywhere you want; it lives on it's own.

On the other hand void* is of pointer size, so you either have to make sure that sizeof (your data) <= sizeof(void*) or your void* is just a pointer to a real data which is stored somewhere else.  But in that case, it is completely different from any<> because now you need to worry about that "somewhere else" and make sure it stays valid as long as void* is valid, which sometimes could become a challenge, especially in multithreaded applications.

Plus as other's have mentioned any<> is very type safe, it'll store anything you want, but the only way to get it back is to know the exact type or it fails (which can be kinda annoying when one API gives you *unsigned int* and your code wants *int* are treated as different types).  void* will let you do anything you want with it and if you start reading or paving over heap and/or uninitialized memory, it won't stop you or even let you know that you are doing that.

Answer (score 5):

This is what boost's reference says:

> It supports copying of any value type and safe checked extraction of
>   that value strictly against its type.

Neither of those can be done with a `void*`. There are no checks for you and you have to know yourself what you can cast it to.

I don't think `dynamic_cast` enters the picture at all, as it hasn't directly anything to do with either.